# Doctrine/Symfony/CollectionType: How persist new items in collection with bidirectional One-To-Many relation?

Tags: forms, symfony, doctrine

I have 2 Entities with bidirectional One-To-Many relations:

```
class EntityA {
  /**
   * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="EntityB", inversedBy="entitiesA")
   * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
   */
  protected $entityB;

  //...

  public function setEntityB(EntityB $entity = null)
  {
    $entity->addEntityA($this);

    $this->entityB = $entity;
  }

  //...
}

class EntityB {
  /**
   * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="EntityA", mappedBy="entityB")
   */
  protected $entitiesA;

  //...

  public function addEntityA(EntityA $entity)
  {
    if(!$this->entitiesA->contains($entity)){
      $this->entitiesA[] = $entity;

      //Make link
      $entity->setEntityB($this);
    }
  }
  //...
}
```

For Form Type, I use a CollectionType:

```
->add('entitiesA', CollectionType::class, array(
    'entry_type'   => EntityBType::class,
    'allow_add'    => true,
    'allow_delete' => true
  ))
```

All things are operational except 1: I think that new items in collection is not linked to the EntityA. Maybe I forgot a process... I have the following error:

> A new entity was found through the relationship 'EntityB#entitiesA' that was not configured to cascade persist operations for entity: EntityA@000000006cf0842c000000004d5dcfd9. To solve this issue: Either explicitly call EntityManager#persist() on this unknown entity or configure cascade persist this association in the mapping for example @ManyToOne(..,cascade={"persist"}). If you cannot find out which entity causes the problem implement 'EntityA#__toString()' to get a clue.

When I add `cascade={"persist"}` like this:

```
class EntityB {
  /**
   * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="EntityA", mappedBy="entityB", cascade={"persist"})
   */
  protected $entitiesA;
```

I have the following error:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Le champ 'entityB_id' ne peut être vide (null)

Do you have any idea to resolve my issue please?

Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @jjoselon for your help. I tried to add `referencedColumnName="id"` but I have the `SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation` again.

However, I found a solution but not clean.

> I add a new field in EntityB but not stored in DB.

```
class EntityB {
  /**
   * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="EntityA", mappedBy="entityB")
   */
  protected $entitiesA;
  protected $entitiesA_new;
```

`$entitiesA_new` will be used for new objects while `$entitiesA` for existing objects

> In Form Type, I add non mapped field:

```
->add('entitiesA_new', CollectionType::class, array(
    'entry_type'   => EntityBType::class,
    'allow_add'    => true,
    'allow_delete' => true,
    'entry_options'  => array(
      "mapped" => false
    )))
  ))
```

> In controller,  after Form validation, I parse all fields of `entitiesA_new` from request and add new objects.

```
$forms_raw = $request->request->get('block_prefix');
if($forms_raw  && isset($forms_raw["entitiesA_new"]))
{
  foreach ($forms_raw["entitiesA_new"] as $entityA_raw)
  {
    $entityA = new EntityA();

    $entityA->setName($entityA_raw["name"]);
    $entityA->setOption($entityA_raw["option"]);
    $entityA->setCategory($entityA_raw["category"]);
    $entityA->setEntityB($entityB);

    $em->persist($entityA);
  }
}
```

So I think there is a better solution but for now, I only have that one.

Answer (score 0):

In my app I have a bidirectional relationship, like this:

Owner side :

```
/**
 * Many users can have many types
 * @var \AppBundle\Entity\TypeOfUser
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\TypeOfUser", inversedBy="type")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="type_user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
protected $typeOfUser;
```

Inverse side

```
/**
 * A type of user can belong to Many Users
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="typeOfUser")
 */
protected $type;
```

Comment: Thank for your answer but with this method, I have another error `A new entity was found through the relationship 'EntityB#entitiesA' that was not configured to cascade persist operations for entity`. This message joins the previous error. I think I shall to do something to link the new objects with owner side, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Le champ 'entityB_id' ne peut être vide (null)

To avoid that, you have to persist and flush entityB before persist and flush entityA